# Phonegap - Notification for any change in youtube api

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, notifications, youtube-api

I want to implement push notification in android and iphone devices for any changes in my youtube channel, that is displayed in my app.

I'm using youtube api to display my channel list in app. Now if I upload a new videos there should be a notification in app also.

Any suggestion or article will be helpful.

Comment: Have you looked at [Urban Airship for Phonegap](http://docs.urbanairship.com/build/phonegap.html)?

Comment: Thanks for link, it'll help, But how can I get the notification from youtube api for any change in channel. Ant idea?